# Should C libraries be header only?

Tags: c

When writing a C library, many developers argue that it should not be header only since that would increase compilation time.

Personally, I'm a little confused by that fact since I'm comparing it to the fact that the standard library is all header only.

So what's the right way to build a library?

Comment: `standard library is all header only.` since when?

Comment: What do you mean by "header only"?

Comment: @SouravGhosh I'm not sure, I just never link to the binary so I assumed they are.

Comment: @AugustKarlstrom As in having the implementation in the header files; so there are no `.c` files, no executable binary.

Comment: no, by default your code is linked with the standard library (ex: libc). If you really want to stop linking, use `-nostdlib` with gcc and see for yourself.

Comment: Also, which function definition you see in standard header files?

Comment: If you include the same variable and function definitions (implementations) in different translation units you cannot link these as there will be name clashes.

Comment: Standard library is a `.lib` file linked by default. It is not header only. And BTW the compile time can be increased because of many header files not the real linking.

Comment: @i486. On Linux, a standard library is some  `.so` file

Comment: Your question lacks details: what is the size (e.g. in source code lines) of the library you are developing? Is it a small project (of a few thousand lines) or a huge internal  library with more than a million lines of C and thousands of source files? Do you have a team of hundred developers? Also, what is your build time (hours?)

Comment: Also, can you afford spending months of work to improve runtime performance of your library by a few % ?

Comment: @SouravGhosh Thank you for the correction, I was mistaken.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch With this question do you expect that he is developing huge library with million lines? This cannot be combined with piece of wisdom like: "it should not be header only since that would increase compilation time".

Comment: @AugustKarlstrom Thank you. You're correct!

Comment: @i486 I didn't know that. Thank you.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch It's a relatively small library and with just a few developers, and we're trying to finish quickly so that's a _no_ for spending months of work to improve runtime performance.

Comment: @i486 I don't want to take your answer personally, but what's my question got to do with my experience? I may not be experienced in C and not know the intricacies of the language, but I'd classify myself as a pretty experienced systems engineer.

Comment: For *small* libraries, having them header only makes sense. For a one million line of C library, it usually does not...e.g. transforming [GTK](http://gtk.org/) to be header only is non-sense.

Comment: It's often not *practical* to build a library where all the library code can simply be `#include`d in a header (or set of headers) - it can impact build times, you risk multiple definition errors or name collisions, etc.  It depends on what the library actually *does*, of course, but for example a good chunk of the C standard library requires you to link against binaries to get the library code itself - the headers (as a rule) do not contain any executable code themselves.

Comment: The standard library is not header-only, as it can refer to definitions outside the headers. On the contrary, it is source-file-free. Note technically headers are _not_ source files and they do not need to be implemented in files.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Personally, I'm a little confused by that fact since I'm comparing it
> to the fact that the standard library is all header only.

No conforming implementation of the C standard library is header-only, at least not in the sense you mean.  We know this, among other reasons, because the language specification says that

> Provided that a library function can be declared without reference to
> any type defined in a header, it is also permissible to declare the
> function and use it without including its associated header.

(C2017, paragraph 7.1.4/2)

That would not be possible if the standard library were header-only. The natural and usual way to implement it is as a *bona fide* normal library, with normal(-ish) headers containing declarations of the provided functions and data types.  Do not be confused by the fact that most C implementations link that library to your programs automatically, without you having to request it.

> So what's the right way to build a library?

There is no one right way to build a library, but header-only libraries are very rare in the C world.  They are more common in C++, but not the norm there, either.  (In particular, the overall C++ standard library also is not header-only.)  Without making it a matter of right *vs* wrong, I would recommend that you not devote any extra effort to producing header-only libraries until and unless you can articulate for yourself a specific purpose that would be served by doing so, and can justify to yourself that the benefits will outweigh the costs.  I wouldn't be surprised if you never reach such a point.

Comment: It is not true a header-only implementation is impossible to be standard-conforming. There can be many alternative implementation strategies. Perhaps the easiest way is to make all definitions be the compiler builtins as if they are external source files (with far less overhead during translation). At least this is feasible for a freestanding implementation which can omit many trouble makers like `malloc`/threading support. OTOH, C++ is not blessed in such ways; at least the mandated exception handling and RTTI are complex enough to get everything worse, in particular when ABI is concerned.

Comment: @FrankHB, if the definitions of some of the standard library functions are not contained in the library headers then it doesn't matter for this purpose where they actually are -- the library is not header-only.  Moreover, most standard library functions are specified to be external functions, so it is possible to obtain pointers to them via the `&` operator.  That means they must exist as actual functions that get linked (in)to the executable.  The standard library doesn't have to be structured the same as an external library, but no, it cannot be header-only.

Comment: In the strict sense you are somewhat right (nothing can be strictly header-only, e.g. you'll ultimately depoly something like libgcc to make header-only libraries work), but this will render "header-only" in the programmers' view useless. And it is still wrong to take `&` a showstopper. The linkage is also ruled by the abstract machine semantic of the language and it is nothing special to be optimized away, once the implementer wants to guarantee it. Practically no vendors do it because it interferes interops and seems just not that worthy.

Comment: @FrankHB, I am exactly right in the appropriate sense of the term "header only".  I'm actually not following what you are using as a definition, but the usual one is the literal one: that the library implementation consists only of headers.  Sure, there are all sorts of potential implementation strategies for the standard library, but they do not include any header-only alternatives.  In particular, your example of making the library functions compiler builtins clearly is not one, as it puts substantial portions of the library in the compiler, as opposed to in headers.

Answer (score 4):

It is really naïve to think, that standard library is all header only. Behind those headers you include in your code, there is *libc* for example, where all functionalities are defined, and those headers are just an "interface" to access them.

I'll recommend to read about .so files, for further understanding.

Answer (score 3):

> When writing a C library, many developers argue that it should not be header only since that would increase compilation time.

### This is [compiler](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compiler) specific.

With a recent [GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/), you might try to compile your header file into a [precompiled header](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Precompiled-Headers.html).

You might try [tinycc](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tiny_C_Compiler): it compiles C code very quickly, but with few [optimizations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optimizing_compiler).

You could use [nwcc](http://nwcc.sourceforge.net/) or even improve it.

You could look into the [CompCert](https://compcert.inria.fr/) project. It compiles well, and give guarantees on the generated code. You could also consider using [Frama-C](https://frama-c.com/) or the [Clang static analyzer](http://clang-analyzer.llvm.org/) to find *some* bugs in your C code at "compile time".

BTW, compilers are fast, and most of the time spent by a developer is no more waiting for the compilation (unless you work on *huge* projects like the Linux [kernel](https://kernel.org/)). But on debugging his/her C code (e.g. with [GDB](https://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/)).

With cross-compilers (e.g. for [Arduino](https://arduino.cc/)), things can be different.

There are (unusual) cases where most of some C library is in some header files. Look into [GNU lightning](https://www.gnu.org/software/lightning/) as an example. A typical (but unusual) reason to have a header-only library is because you want *all* functions to be `static inline` so that the compiler could optimize them better. Header-only libraries are unusual,  they have only `*.h` files and no `*.c` files.

**If you develop a header only library, I strongly recommend to document it well, and to have some naming conventions** (e.g. all names are starting with the same prefix...) to lower the possibility of name clashes.

However, read [*Modern C*](https://modernc.gforge.inria.fr/) and see [this](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c) C reference. In most cases, the source code of a library coded in C has both header (`*.h`) and implementation (`*.c`) files, so several [translation units](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Translation_unit_(programming)). However, [sqlite](https://sqlite.org/) is a known exception.

Also, you can write programs (on GNU/Linux) which generates some C code at runtime in some temporary file, compile that temporary file (using `gcc -Wall -Wextra -O2 -fPIC`) into a plugin, and load that plugin into the current process with [dlopen(3)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/dlopen.3.html) and [dlsym(3)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/dlsym.3.html). See my [manydl.c](https://github.com/bstarynk/misc-basile/blob/master/manydl.c) as an example.

You could also improve the [GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/) compiler by writing (in C++ today) your [GCC plugin](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gccint/Plugins.html).

> So what's the right way to build a library?

The traditional way is to edit your C source files (e.g. with [GNU emacs](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/)), perhaps *generate* some C code (e.g. with [GNU bison](https://www.gnu.org/software/bison/)), probably have some `Makefile` for [GNU make](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/) (but you might generate that with [GNU automake](https://www.gnu.org/software/automake/) and [GNU autoconf](https://www.gnu.org/software/autoconf/)), and build your library using `make`. You'll want to use some version control system e.g. [git](https://git-scm.com/). And you might study (for inspiration) the source code of [GNU libc](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/), of [libcurl](https://curl.se/libcurl/), or of [libonion](https://coralbits.com/static/onion/) (and many others open source libraries)

### In practice, building a library is [operating system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operating_system) specific.

With a powerful desktop machine, compilation time is usually less than a few minutes. The [Phoronix](https://www.phoronix.com/) and [OpenBenchMarking](https://openbenchmarking.org/) websites may give interesting figures.

Of course, compiling from scratch (see [LinuxFromScratch](https://linuxfromscratch.org/) for hints) a large C library like [GTK](https://gtk.org/) can take more than a hour. But you rarely do that, and if you contribute to GTK, you probably would update a few source files at one, and you should ask for a powerful multi-core desktop.

For Linux, read Drepper's paper [*How to write shared libraries*](https://software.intel.com/sites/default/files/m/a/1/e/dsohowto.pdf) and [elf(5)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/elf.5.html).

> So what's the right way to build a library?

### It depends.

If you use  [GNU make](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/), you would run the `make`  command. If you use [ninja](https://ninja-build.org/), you would run `ninja`.  If your editor is [GNU emacs](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/), you could configure your `~/.emacs` file to run a compilation with a single keystroke. See [my `.emacs` file](https://github.com/bstarynk/misc-basile/blob/master/.emacs) for inspiration.

In some cases, you'll need to do some [code refactoring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_refactoring).

---

PS. In most parts of the world, the labor cost - for a few months of work - of a software developer is more expensive (in 2020) than the computer he/she needs for software development. So the cost of development for a library is most labor cost, not computer time cost. For example, my [bismon](https://github.com/bstarynk/bismon/) software usually builds in less than a few minutes. And [Pitrat's CAIA system](https://github.com/bstarynk/caia-pitrat) (described in his book [*Artificial Beings: the conscience of a conscious machine*](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1848211015)) is made of half a millions lines of C code (all generated by `caia`) and requires a few minutes to get built.

Answer (score 3):

The right way to build a library module is to provide a header file (a .h file) which contains the exported *declarations*, and an implementation file (a .c file) which contains the variable and function *definitions*. On the other hand, if everything is put in one file which is included in different C files you will end up with multiple definitions of variables and functions and the linker will complain. Also by providing a header file you can distribute a compiled version of your library.

Comment: Maybe using header guards or `include` guards fixes the problem of multiple definitions: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Include_guard